# Plot surface in 3D where f(x,y,z) vanishes

Tags: octave

I have a function

f(x,y,z) = 1 + 2xyz - x*x - y*y - z*z. My range of interest is [-1,1] in any variable.

Obviously, I could not construct a human visible 4D Plot, but I could plot the points in 3D where it vanishes, or fill with red the range where it is positive.

Having forgotten almost everything about matlab and octave, I searched examples and tried:

```
[x y z] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1, -1:0.1:1, -1:0.1:1);
coords = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
V = 1.0 + 2*x.*y.*z -y.*y - z.*z - x.*x;
for p = 1: 1:100
 if V(p) >=0
 c = 'red';
scatter3(x(:,p),y(:,p), z(:,p), 'c');
 end
  end
```

It produces a plot, but it must be bogus, because there are no red dots and 1,1,1 is a solution, which doesn’t show up in the plot. Also the z axis is messed up, showing only negative values.

Please help.

The Plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[x y z] = meshgrid(  -1 : 0.1 : 1,  -1 : 0.1 : 1,  -1 : 0.1 : 1  );
V       = 1.0 + 2 * x .* y .* z - y .* y - z .* z - x .* x;

scatter3( x(:), y(:), z(:), 100,  V(:), 'filled' );
```

[image]

Comment: What controls the colour for a given value of V here?

Comment: @Ludi the `colormap` active at the time. From `help scatter3`: _"The color of the markers is determined by C, which can be a string
     defining a fixed color; a 3-element vector giving the red, green,
     and blue components of the color; **a vector of the same length as X
     that gives a scaled index into the current colormap**; or an Nx3
     matrix defining the RGB color of each marker individually."_

Comment: "Scaled index" here means that the lowest value in V will be assigned the first value in the colormap, the highest value in V will be assigned the last, and in-between values will select suitable colours from the colormap via linear interpolation of some sort.